# Using HTML Forms to pass data to Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to use inputs from a HTML form into a Javascript code. The inputs are 3 zip codes and the result is computation of distance between them and it is followed  by a simple asthmatics. When I click on the submit button it gives erro: Not Found. Where did I go wrong in this? Code is below-

```
  <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
*Enter 5 digit US ZipCodes<br><br>
Port ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" name="PortZip" value="31402">
<br><br>
Importer ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" name="ImporterZip" value="30308">
<br><br>
Exporter ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" name="ExporterZip" value="30901">
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<div id="zip_code_output"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:650px; height:600px;"></div>


<?php
<title>Distance Matrix Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

     //INITIALIZE GLOBAL VARIABLES
     var zipCodesToLookup1 = new Array('$PortZip', '$ImporterZip', '$ExporterZip', '$PortZip');
     var output           = '<tr><th scope="col">From</th><th scope="col">To</th><th scope="col">Miles</th></tr>';
     var difference = "0";
     var totalDist = 0;
    // document.write(difference);
     //EXECUTE THE DISTANCE MATRIX QUERY
     var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
     service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins:      zipCodesToLookup1,
          destinations: zipCodesToLookup1,
          travelMode:   google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem:   google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
     }, function(response, status) {
          if(status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
               var origins = response.originAddresses;
               var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
               for(var i=0; i < origins.length-1; i++) {
                     var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                     output += '<tr><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td>' + destinations[i+1] + '</td><td>' + results[i+1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
                     if (i != 0){
                     totalDist += results[i+1].distance.value;
                     }
                     else {
                     totalDist -= results[i+1].distance.value;
                     }

               }
              output += '<tr><td></td><td>ADDITIONAL DISTANCE -</td><td>'+(totalDist/1000*0.621371).toFixed(0)+ ' mi</td></tr>';


               document.getElementById('zip_code_output').innerHTML = '<table cellpadding="5">' + output + '</table>';
          }
     });
}

//FUNCTION TO LOAD THE GOOGLE MAPS API
function loadScript() {
     var script  = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src  = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDZpAoR25KSkPTRIvI3MZoAg1NL6f0JV0&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is your javascript in a php tag? You didn't end the html form tag

Comment: @Patrick Murphy I ended the html form as </form>.Also I closed the form as <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">, the output is coming with ">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form method="post" action="/">` Don't forget to close the opening `<form>`. That should help.

Comment: I did it. With <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">, the output is coming with ">

Comment: <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post"> this should do it for you, otherwise you should get at least new results along with taking your JS out of your <?php ?> tag as @Karvy1 suggested

Comment: Do I need to have php here or I can directly pass the html inputs into the JS?

Comment: No you can simply use a / in your post action and get rid of the php but the thing is, if you are posting to this same file, what code do you have in place to intercept the post data? It should all be on this same page based on what your doing here. I think your approach here may be off a bit. May I suggest  doing all of this in javascript? If you aren't going to store any of this information I don't think you will be needing to send anything to the server. You will need to pass your server variables into the script as well - the way you have it now is being seen by the browser as a js string

Comment: You are right. I am not sending anything to server. Could you suggest a way with JS only?

Comment: show us what you tried using js and whats not working on your attempt.